# Performance counter for MySql to monitor Transactions per second

Tags: mysql, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

I am working on performance testing of web application which is using MySql/Innodb at its backend. I am using JMeter as a performance testing tool which comes with a [DBMon listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DbMon/).

I need to provide MySQL performance counters (for transactions per second) to JMeter's DBMon listener so it can collect the required data and show it to me in graphical view. I want to know if MySql comes with such counters and how I can use them in my scenario.

DBMON screenshot: http://jmeter-plugins.org/img/wiki/dbmon_samples_collector.png

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Provide a code that you using instead

Comment: I am not using any code. This is simply a screenshot of JMeter plugin that I intend to use with JMeter.